# Buffer.toString() not the same with the original sent data

Tags: node.js, base64

I am doing a Foto with the webcam and then converting the canvas to a .jpg image. Then I am sending the converted to `base64` image to the server and use `data.toString()` for the conversion back to `base 64`.

I am using the `npm` package `base64ToImage` for converting the foto back and saving it. 
The problem is with the conversion back to `base64`. The error `invalid base64 string` is shown.

I compared the `base64` from `client` with the one from `server` and they do not match. Why? So i cant covert the image back.

Please help, I am at the end of my patience, as I know the solution has to be easy.

**Edit:** As the data has more than 600k caract, I'm only posting a part of it:

-this is from the `client`: `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAoAAAAHgCAYAAAA10dzkAAAgAElEQVR4XsS9Wa9kWXodts8QcW9mdlV3cWiyW2yqJXEAKMjwk/XiBz/4zc/+PfaTAVsjRYlNtmXSBvyTDD8IoFqUaEqsrq4xM++9EWcw1vSdHVHVgABxiEYjK/PGjThnn72/vfb61re+4Z/+43+0j+PQHk5zG4ahXa7PbVu3tre1bevatmVv4zi26fTQrtdru+6tTfPUpnFo+763cbu0bd/bNKwNr+104ucsy9a2bWvreOH7tmFr4zS2aT/xfePyin+2febPh3njX6/bkz63DXrfPvLz8OKfw8Kfz+uV13WaR17Xu/XU1mVty9O5Leva9v3c5tPcv`

-this is from the `server`: `imgBase64=data%3Aimage%2Fpng%3Bbase64%2CiVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAoAAAAHgCAYAAAA10dzkAAAgAElEQVR4Xpy9aZMkS3Ic6HFlVfebAZe%2FmSL8sisQEjtczIFjcA24Xyj8aSQx012VGceKXuae%2BRoQyiYE0vO6qzIzItzN1dTU1Kb%2F63d%2Fd23b1t4ej3acR7uuo03T1M71bMs8t2XZ2nVd7XxMDa%2B5nfxzuk7%2B%2FdI%2B2rou%2FB3896O9t8f%2BaB%2FX2uZlbtNjbs`

Comment: `base64-to-image` package require `base64` mime type prefix (e.g. `data:image/jpeg;base64, BASE_64_CONTENT`). Could you check if it present in the result of `data.toString()`?

Comment: Yes it is, but i compared the base64 from the client and the one from the server and they do not match 100%. For example the `+` is `%` and then also some letters are different etc.

Comment: Can you paste sample data?

Comment: I added to the post

Comment: Well one thing i notice is that the content is being URL encoded, which may be an issue depending on the way you're sending the data. but that shouldn't change the body of the base64 string itself, and it's evident that it has changed.

Comment: Ok. Maybe you know how properly send and receive the data?